# .htaccess to search events with a nice looking url

Tags: php, .htaccess, search

I'd like code for a .htaccess file that when this is entered:
domain.com/event/granniesteaparty a file in the folder 'event' (display.php) takes the 'granniesteaparty' bit as though domain.com/event/display.php?search=granniesteaparty had been entered.

If tried all sorts of things but this is where I am at the moment:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^event/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /event/display.php?search=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} s=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^event /event/1? [NC,R=301]
```

I hope that makes sense, could someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 2):

You have too many capture groups in your first rule. Give this a try

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /+event/display\.php\?search=([^&\s]+)
RewriteRule ^ /event/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^event/(\w+)/?$ /event/display.php?search=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for looking at this.  I've pasted your code into the htaccess file and the page said Not Found.  I used domain.com/event/granniesteaparty to test it.  If I enter domain.com/event/display.php it does find the file, I don't know if that helps?

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite or .htaccess files enabled? Put some random text at the top of your .htaccess file, if it causes and error then apache is reading the .htaccess file if nothing happens it's not reading the .htaccess file and you need to enable htaccess usage.

Comment: I put Blah Blah at the top and it caused a server error so it must be working.

Comment: I've got the htaccess file in the event folder.  Does that change anything?

Comment: It does matter where it's located. Put this .htaccess file in the root of your website.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code  `.htaccess` inside event directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+event/display.php?search= [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ event/display.php?search=$1 [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^event/display.php?search=$1(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC]
```

> Update

If you want only to redirect any wrong page to the display page but internally so the following code will do it :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteRule ^(.*)   event/display.php [L,NC]
```

So when someone request `/event/whateverwrong` it will be at the `url` as it is but internally will map to `display.php`

Comment: Thank you Mohammed.  There are no errors showing and the page is displaying the correct output.   
Is there a way of the URL not then displaying domain.com/event/display.php?search= granniesteaparty but continuing to say domain.com/event/granniesteaparty instead? Or am I missing the point?

Comment: Glad to help , and regrading your question see the update

Comment: I think I need a combination of the two.  Your first go was the closest, I still need to pass the variable into the display.php page but would like the url to stay the same (kind of cloaked - domain.com/event/granniesteaparty).
So the granniesteaparty bit is passed to the page in the search variable domain.com/event/display.php?search=granniesteaparty)
Thanks again.